# Add TransformGroup to a TransformGroup in wp7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am applying rendertransform on textbox, I want to add a TransformGroup object inside a TransformGroup Object.
for doing that, I am doing somewhat like this in xaml.

```
                  <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <MatrixTransform x:Name="previousTransform" />

                        <TransformGroup x:Name="currentTransform">
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
                            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </TextBox.RenderTransform>
```

And it works the way I expected, now I want the same to happen inside c#, I have made a TransformGroup object and managed to add transforms to it. Now I want to add this transform group to another transformgroup object like how I did in xaml but, I dont know how to do it.
Please give suggestions on the property or method I shall use to achieve it.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      var textBox = new TextBox();
      var transformGroup = new TransformGroup()
          {
              Children = new TransformCollection()
                  {
                      new MatrixTransform(), 
                      new TransformGroup
                      { 
                          Children = new TransformCollection()
                          {
                              new ScaleTransform(), 
                              new RotateTransform(), 
                              new TranslateTransform()
                          }
                      }
                  }
          };

      textBox.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
```